# Applying another formula in a python function if a certain condition is met

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function in python that generates an array of outputs using a specific formula but uses another formula if a certain condition is met.

The code I wrote is,

```
import numpy as np

def fun(a,b):
for i in range(len(b)):
    if a != b[i]:
        return a+b[i]
    elif a == b[i]:
        return a-b[i]

a=1
b=np.array([5,4,1,2,3])

fun(a,b)
```

and I get as a result,

```
6
```

rather than,

```
array([6, 5, 0, 3, 4])
```

can anyone direct me towards the appropriate code for this task, I would like to generalize the idea over more complex formulas.

Comment: You are returning values, as numbers instead of appending them into a new list.

Comment: If you `return` inside a function, either inside or loop or not, it immediately exits the function without further iteration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your approach is that it `return`s on the very first iteration instead of creating a list and appending to it then returning that list.

With a list comprehension (unfortunately `np.array` does not work with generator expressions):

```
def fun(a, b):
    return np.array([n - 1 if n == a else n + 1 for n in b])
```

---

**But** since you are using numpy you would be better off using the tools it offers.

In this case, [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
a = 1
b = np.array([5,4,1,2,3])
print(np.where(b == 1, b - 1, b + 1))
```

Outputs

```
[6 5 0 3 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to calculate each value, append it to a list and finally return the list

```
import numpy as np

def fun(a,b):
    res = []
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if a != b[i]:
            val =  a+b[i]
        elif a == b[i]:
            val = a-b[i]
        res.append(val)
    return res

a=1
b=np.array([5,4,1,2,3])

fun(a,b)
```

Comment: In this case you don't return a numpy array. A more efficient way would be to allocate res with np.zeros_like(b) once instead of appending.

Answer (score 1):

once return is executed, the execution of the function stops

**Use**

```
import numpy as np

def fun(a,b):

    my_list=[]
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if a != b[i]:
            my_list.append(a+b[i])
        elif a == b[i]:
            my_list.append(a-b[i])
    return np.array(my_list)
a=1
b=np.array([5,4,1,2,3])

fun(a,b)
```

Output:

```
array([6, 5, 0, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to build a return object and then return it once at the end of the function, rather than returning inside the loop.

Something along the lines of:

```
def fun(a, b):
    result = np.zeros_like(b)
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if ...:
            result[i] = a+b[i]
        else:
            ...
    return result
```